# What is the biggest new feature/improvement in SharePoint 2010? 

Tags: 2010

Of all the new features and improvements in SharePoint 2010, which one (or area or feature set) do you think will have the biggest impact on the SharePoint world?

Comment: I'm closing this because it is no longer relevant with SP2013 in beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the Service Application (formally SSP) architecture is the biggest and most impressive change.  Each application is now seperatable out so that it can be hosted in its own web app running against its own database.

It is also possible to access a service application from outside the farm.  This means that we can have farms dedicated to a certain Service Application which can be accessed by all SharePoint installations in an enterprice environment.  This is great for scaling and having a clean architecture.  It also means that you can have some Service Applications that are be enterprise wide accessed by SharePoint farms that have their own Service Applications for specific tasks.

This is also going to make developing shared applications a load easier.

AC has written a nice overview here...

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/10/19/the-new-service-application-architecture-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

Comment: and Spence goes more in depth here...

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010sa.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Client Object Model](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/2009/08/19/SharePoint-2010-Introducing-the-Client-Object-Model.aspx) is a Big Plus IMHO

Answer (score 2):

The new Business Connectivity Services is huge IMHO.

Comment: This is obviously my favourite! :-) BDC was certainly good, but BCS is not only adding more functionality and features but also making it available to more people as the core parts are now in SharePoint Foundation

Answer (score 2):

I would definetely have to say all the progress made in Document & Records management, including the Metadata system, tagging, document sets, content type hub and in-place records management.

Since most organizations start out using SharePoint as a document repository, its also one of the areas they struggle to keep control of.  Many of the new 2010 SP tools allow you to streamline your DM practices and enhance the ease of use from a user perspective.

One caveat is to implement is going to take more planning and a stronger governance structure.  Organizations will also have to decided how far back to re-work DM system with new features, or just to start with new content.

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective as an administrator the Health Check and the Developer Dashboard are two of the best tools provided. Not only will I be able to troubleshoot my farm, but also individual pages. I will be able o  a schedule for reviewing these checks and ensuring that the farm performance is optimized. I will also be able to be proactive in discovering pages that are slower and assist end users or developers in correcting all contributing issues.

Another nice thing about the health check, is that you can use the canned best practices, but you can also tweak these and even create your own set of practices that you want to ensure are followed.

Answer (score 1):

From a developer perspective [Sandboxed solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539083%28office.14%29.aspx) will have a huge impact for custom app development on top of SharePoint platform. This feature allows site admins (not just farm admins) to easily upload custom solutions even to hosted environments. APIs available to SB solutions is somewhat limited but still allows you to do a lot. Farm admins can also control these sandboxes and limit them as they see fit for their environment.

There is a number of improvements in the development, packaging and specially in the field of connecting to other LOBs even without custom code from SharePoint Designer and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be the integration of visual studio and sharepoint.

Visual studio 2008 knows nothing about sharepoint.Debugging and deploying is such a pain. I now can see the end of this in sight, :) no more silly remote debuging
I can't wait to use visual studio 2010 in anger.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many new features to pick just one! I'm excited about a lot of the new admin related features, a couple that Lori already mentioned. The unattached database is great to allow you to retreive granular content without having to attach the database in Sharepoint. In 2007, you would have to build a separate farm for database restores, since you could not have duplicate GUIDs in the same farm. Also, errors now have Correlation IDs which makes it much easier to locate them in the ULS logs, as well as being shown in every SQL request. Locating specific issues will be much easier. And who could leave out PowerShell?!?! 652 cmdlets!

Answer (score 1):

SPMetal and Linq for SharePoint adds nice functionality from a developer's perspective

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/02/19/sp-2010-getting-started-with-linq-to-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I love the RESTful interfaces

Answer (score 0):

My Favorite feature/improvement

Best of all is the Insights ( Performance Point , Chart Webparts , PowerPivot..etc)

Developer:

- Client Side Object Model
- RESTful /SPMetal
- Developer DashBoard
- Cross browser / XHTML complaint Masterpages / new Styles :)

Admin/Dev:

- PowerShell
- SSP Architecture
- List Throttling

Organization :

- Managed MetaData
- Document Sets
- FAST Search Integration

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party :) If by "SharePoint world" you mean end-users, developers, designers, admins, etc. then I must say the UI/UX.

There are still many improvement that should be made to the UI/UX, but overall the UI/UX is a lot more cleaner and smoother. The reason for picking this feature is because no matter which feature affects you, you will notice the UI/UX.

Comment: You are a little late for SP2010, but you could say the same about SP2013 ;-)